# R/Knime: plotting multiple curves in a single plot using a R snippet inside a KNIME loop

Tags: r, plot, knime

I'm new to both knime and R so sorry if my question is a bit silly.

I've created a simple workflow to:

1) open multiple file and join them togheter with only one x axis (PPM) and several y axis (the name is created through the cycle from the file location)

2)plot each indivual x and y couple and save them to a specific folder (with a R snippet)

3)plot all the curve in a single plot (with a R snippet) with different line style

The last point unfortunately is not working and I don't know why.

Here is the link to Gdrive with the workflow and some data

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6XSS-i7eUt7SlRVOWZ2RElKa0k/edit?usp=sharing

Any help (and suggestion to improve the code) will be appreciated :)

Cheers,

Michele

Comment: This is a place to help you with difficulties, but not to do your work for you. What have you tried?

Comment: Can you make your problem reproducible without external links (which I don't see)?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik sorry I forgot to attach it :)

Comment: @BorisStitnicky I tried all the solution proposed for R (such as par(new=TRUE),using lines to add the following plots, etc...etc... The main problem I had with them is that they don't take in account the fact that the R script is running inside a loop...